# Transferring questions to other sites using voting mechanism?

Tags: feature-request, migration, vote-to-close, moderation, off-topic

I see people talk about questions being asked in the wrong Stack Exchange site.

Can a question not be transferred to another Stack Exchange site, using the same vote mechanism?

Comment: Stack Exchange is not Forum, and take a look / or suggest them to look at [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#mainbar-full)

Comment: Questions can be and are moved between sites. You need 3,000 rep or more to vote to close (which includes migration), but you can flag a question for moderator attention if you think it should be moved.

Comment: This already happens, it's called "migration". However, not every SE site can be voted for as a migration target.

Comment: What the hell is a forum?

Answer (score 3):

Once 5 people with sufficient reputation to close the question vote to have it migrated, then the question is migrated, and only moderators on the two sites can reverse it.

If you see a question that appears as though it might get migrated, and you disagree with the decisions others are making about it, you should indicate your reasons as a comment to the question, and try to convince them that the question is on topic for the site it's already on.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that vote to close has a should be on [enter stack exchange site here] option. However talking about a question not belonging helps educate users as to what type of questions should be asked where. I'd far prefer to see a reason for why one of my questions was migrated over a silent migration.